# How to get year/month/day from a date object?

Tags: javascript, date

`alert(dateObj)` gives `Wed Dec 30 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0800`

How to get date in format `2009/12/30`?

Comment: You wanted UTC date and time?

Answer (score 603, accepted):

```
const dateObj = new Date();
const month   = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; // months from 1-12
const day     = dateObj.getUTCDate();
const year    = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

const newDate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

// Using template literals:
const newDate = `${year}/${month}/${day}`;

// Using padded values, so that 2023/1/7 becomes 2023/01/07
const pMonth        = month.toString().padStart(2,"0");
const pDay          = day.toString().padStart(2,"0");
const newPaddedDate = `${year}/${pMonth}/${pDay}`;
```

or you can set new date and give the above values

Comment: Just remember: January=0, February=1, and so on.

Comment: What's the difference between `getMonth` and `getUTCMonth`?

Comment: UTC will return universal time.
if you want local time use getMonth

Comment: `getUTCDay()` should be replaced by `getUTCDate()`, since day is the number of the day in week (0-6) and date is the number of the day in month (1-31).

Comment: This response is still flawed I believe.
getUTCDate() will return the Day of the month indeed but in England.

For example if I type:
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
d.getDate() returns 21
but d.getUTCDate() returns only 20

This is because at 01:15 in the morning in France (where I am), it is still 23:15 in England.

To get the day that was in the original Date you should use getDate().

Comment: @PascalGanaye Regardless whether the response is flawed or not (strictly taken considering the question it actually is), what you say is not only true for the day. It applies also for month and year (consider e.g. "Jan 1, 1983 01:15:00").

Comment: year,month and day should be padded with 0 like

newdate = [year, month, day].map((num) => `0${num}`.slice(-2) ).join("/");

Comment: "getUTCDate()" should be replaced by (getUTCDate() + 1) or getDate()

Answer (score 202):

```
new Date().toISOString()
"2016-02-18T23:59:48.039Z"
new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
"2016-02-18"
new Date().toISOString().replace('-', '/').split('T')[0].replace('-', '/');
"2016/02/18"

new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0]
"2/18/2016"
```

Comment: I think this could be better for third case    
new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/-/g, '/');

Comment: using `replaceAll`instead of `replace` would make more sense. Example: `new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].replaceAll('-', '/')`

Answer (score 119):

```
var dt = new Date();

dt.getFullYear() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate();
```

Since month index are 0 based you have to increment it by 1.

***Edit***

For a complete list of date object functions see

**[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date)**

```
getMonth()
```

Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to local time.

```
getUTCMonth()
```

Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to universal time.

Comment: Needs parens.  Otherwise october will show up as month 91 (since 9 + 1 = 91 in stringland)

Comment: Should be

dt.getFullYear() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate();

Answer (score 66):

Why not using the method `toISOString()` with `slice` or simply [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)?

Beware that the timezone returned by `toISOString` is always zero UTC offset, whereas in `toLocaleDateString` it is the user agent's timezone.

Check here:

```js
const d = new Date() // today, now

// Timezone zero UTC offset
console.log(d.toISOString().slice(0, 10)) // YYYY-MM-DD

// Timezone of User Agent
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')) // YYYY-MM-DD
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('en-US')) // M/D/YYYY
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('de-DE')) // D.M.YYYY
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-PT')) // DD/MM/YYYY
```

Comment: For anyone whose getting back dates from Mongo & need them in `year/month/day` this is your answer ^^^.  Example: `new Date("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").toISOString().slice(0,10)
`

Comment: great answer!  maybe someday there'll be a `.toISODateString()` that does this.

Comment: This gives me a wrong date, `new Date(1618264800000).toLocaleDateString()` => "13.4.2021", but `new Date(1618264800000).toISOString().slice(0, 10)` => "2021-04-12". So it's one day diff.

Comment: : @dude it depends on the UTC or locale time, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 38):

**2021 ANSWER**

You can use the native `.toLocaleDateString()` function which supports several useful params like **locale** (to select a format like MM/DD/YYYY or YYYY/MM/DD), **timezone** (to convert the date) and **formats details options** (eg: 1 vs 01 vs January).

**Examples**

```js
console.log( new Date().toLocaleDateString() ); // 8/19/2020
    
console.log( new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}) ); // 08/19/2020 (month and day with two digits)

console.log( new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-ZA') ); // 2020/08/19 (year/month/day) notice the different locale
    
console.log( new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA') ); // 2020-08-19 (year-month-day) notice the different locale

console.log( new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}) ); // 8/19/2020, 9:29:51 AM. (date and time in a specific timezone)

console.log( new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {hour: '2-digit', hour12: false, timeZone: "America/New_York"}) );  // 09 (just the hour)
```

Notice that sometimes to output a date in your specific desire format, you have to find a compatible locale with that format.
You can find the locale examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocalestring_date_all

Please notice that **locale** just change the format, if you want to transform a specific date to a specific country or city time equivalent then you need to use the **timezone** param.

Comment: Works perfectly 

Comment: A reminder answer like this is excatly what I needed! I always forgot the additional param for `.toLocaleDateString()`

Answer (score 35):

I would suggest you to use Moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Then you can do:

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
```

Note: you don't actualy need to add `new Date()` if you want the current TimeDate, I only added it as a reference that you can pass a date object to it. for the current TimeDate this also works:

```
moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD");
```

Comment: This answer is good if you wish to add a dependency - and if so as of 2019 day.js is a lighter weight alternative to moment.js as an option to consider - https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs. Also mentioned there is Luxon and date-fns.

Answer (score 24):

```
let dateObj = new Date();

let myDate = (dateObj.getUTCFullYear()) + "/" + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + (dateObj.getUTCDate());
```

For reference you can see the below details

```
new Date().getDate()          // Return the day as a number (1-31)
new Date().getDay()           // Return the weekday as a number (0-6)
new Date().getFullYear()      // Return the four digit year (yyyy)
new Date().getHours()         // Return the hour (0-23)
new Date().getMilliseconds()  // Return the milliseconds (0-999)
new Date().getMinutes()       // Return the minutes (0-59)
new Date().getMonth()         // Return the month (0-11)
new Date().getSeconds()       // Return the seconds (0-59)
new Date().getTime()          // Return the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
```

```js
let dateObj = new Date();

let myDate = (dateObj.getUTCFullYear()) + "/" + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + (dateObj.getUTCDate());

console.log(myDate)
```

Comment: The UTC versions of these methods get you the year, month, etc. in UTC. Mixing them with the non-UTC versions will get you nonsensical output (unless you're currently on GMT, in which case you won't notice, but your users will).

Answer (score 22):

**info**

If a 2 digit month and date is desired (2016/01/01 vs 2016/1/1)

**code**

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = ('0' + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var date = ('0' + dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2);
var year = dateObj.getFullYear();
var shortDate = year + '/' + month + '/' + date;
alert(shortDate);
```

**output**

2016/10/06

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/1xuu7z7h/

**credit**

More info from and [credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605248/3377049)

**more**

To learn more about `.slice` the [try it yourself editor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) at w3schools helped me understand better how to use it.

Comment: But if the date is set to Decemeber, it doesn't forward to January next year?

Answer (score 22):

```
var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
"12/30/2009"
```

Comment: To compare 2 dates this answer is top. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Use the Date get methods.

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470841

```
var dateobj= new Date() ;
var month = dateobj.getMonth() + 1;
var day = dateobj.getDate() ;
var year = dateobj.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Months on JavaScript Date objects are zero-indexed. Be sure to add 1 to it, else December gets to be November; November gets to be October and so forth

Comment: @Aseem Should just be the month that needs the +1

Answer (score 15):

Nice formatting add-in: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format.

With that you could write:

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("yyyy/mm/dd");
```

Answer (score 9):

**EUROPE (ENGLISH/SPANISH) FORMAT**
I you need to get the current day too, you can use this one.

```
function getFormattedDate(today) 
{
    var week = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    var day  = week[today.getDay()];
    var dd   = today.getDate();
    var mm   = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minu = today.getMinutes();

    if(dd<10)  { dd='0'+dd } 
    if(mm<10)  { mm='0'+mm } 
    if(minu<10){ minu='0'+minu } 

    return day+' - '+dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy+' '+hour+':'+minu;
}

var date = new Date();
var text = getFormattedDate(date);
```

*For Spanish format, just translate the WEEK variable.

```
var week = new Array('Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado');
```

Output: **Monday - 16/11/2015 14:24**

Answer (score 8):

With the accepted answer, January 1st would be displayed like this: `2017/1/1`.

If you prefer `2017/01/01`, you can use:

```
var dt = new Date();
var date = dt.getFullYear() + '/' + (((dt.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0' : '') + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + ((dt.getDate() < 10) ? '0' : '') + dt.getDate();
```

Answer (score 4):

One liner, using destructuring.

Makes 3 variables of type **string**:

```
const [year, month, day] = (new Date()).toISOString(). substring(0, 10).split('-')
```

Makes 3 variables of type **number** (integer):

```
const [year, month, day] = (new Date()).toISOString(). substring(0, 10).split('-').map(x => parseInt(x, 10))
```

From then, it's easy to **combine** them any way you like:

```js
const [year, month, day] = (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10).split('-');
console.log(year, month, day);
const dateFormatted = `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
console.log(dateFormatted);
```

Comment: Great answer! Works for me!  It may be better to use substring(), as substr() is marked as deprecated on the Mozilla developers website. `This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards ... Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaner way getting Year/Month/Day with template literals:

```js
var date = new Date();
var formattedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}/${(date.getMonth() + 1)}/${date.getDate()}`;
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

> It's Dynamic It will collect the language from user's browser setting

> Use **minutes** and **hour** property in the **option** object to work with them..
> You can use **long** value to represent month like Augest 23 etc...

```
function getDate(){
 const now = new Date()
 const option = {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric'
 }
 const local = navigator.language
 labelDate.textContent = `${new 
 Intl.DateTimeFormat(local,option).format(now)}`
}
getDate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use This one line code to get date in year-month-date format

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + new Date().getMonth() + 1 + "-" + new Date().getDate();
```

Answer (score 1):

ES2018 introduced regex capture groups which you can use to catch day, month and year:

```
const REGEX = /(?<year>[0-9]{4})-(?<month>[0-9]{2})-(?<day>[0-9]{2})/;
const results = REGEX.exec('2018-07-12');
console.log(results.groups.year);
console.log(results.groups.month);
console.log(results.groups.day);
```

Advantage of this approach is possiblity to catch day, month, year for non-standard string date formats.

Ref. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/es9-javascripts-state-of-art-in-2018-9a350643f29c/

Comment: The question was specifically asking about formatting a date in "month/day/year" from a Date object. Capture groups in regex are not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentYear = date.getFullYear() ;
let currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1 ; // 0 - 11
let currentDay = date.getDate() ; 
  
//The padStart() method pads the current string with another string (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the given length.
// 0-9 it will pad 0 at beginning
// 10 - 31 it will not pad     
const addPad = (num) => {
   return num.toString().padStart(2,'0')
}

console.log(addPad(10)) // 10 
console.log(addPad(1)) // 01  0-9 it will pad 0 at begining


let dateWithSlash = [ addPad(currentDay) , addPad(currentMonth) ,  currentYear].join("/")  // 01/01/2023
let dateWithHyphen = [ addPad(currentDay) , addPad(currentMonth) ,  currentYear].join("-") // 01-01-2023
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using this which works if you pass it a date obj or js timestamp:

```
getHumanReadableDate: function(date) {
    if (date instanceof Date) {
         return date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    } else if (isFinite(date)) {//timestamp
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(date);
        return this.getHumanReadableDate(d);
    }
}
```