# Javascript add leading zeroes to date

Tags: javascript, date, date-format, time-format, leading-zero

I've created this script to calculate the date for 10 days in advance in the format of dd/mm/yyyy:

```
var MyDate = new Date();
var MyDateString = new Date();
MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate()+10);
MyDateString = MyDate.getDate() + '/' + (MyDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + MyDate.getFullYear();
```

I need to have the date appear with leading zeroes on the day and month component by way of adding these rules to the script. I can't seem to get it to work.

```
if (MyDate.getMonth < 10)getMonth = '0' + getMonth;
```

and

```
if (MyDate.getDate <10)get.Date = '0' + getDate;
```

If someone could show me where to insert these into the script I would be really appreciative.

Comment: As a good convention, you should lowercase the first character in your variable names and reserve camel casing for objects/prototypes.

Comment: If the YYYY-MM-DD format is acceptable, this would be a very good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431880/1717535

Comment: Scroll down for ES6+ `padStart` answer

Answer (score 1662, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xA5B7/

```
var MyDate = new Date();
var MyDateString;

MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate() + 20);

MyDateString = ('0' + MyDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
             + ('0' + (MyDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
             + MyDate.getFullYear();
```

---

**EDIT:**

To explain, `.slice(-2)` gives us the *last* two characters of the string.

So no matter what, we can add `"0"` to the day or month, and just ask for the last two since those are always the two we want.

So if the `MyDate.getMonth()` returns `9`, it will be:

```
("0" + "9") // Giving us "09"
```

so adding `.slice(-2)` on that gives us the last two characters which is:

```
("0" + "9").slice(-2)
"09"
```

But if `MyDate.getMonth()` returns `10`, it will be:

```
("0" + "10") // Giving us "010"
```

so adding `.slice(-2)` gives us the last two characters, or:

```
("0" + "10").slice(-2)
"10"
```

Comment: Forked - date format YYYY-MM-DD

http://jsfiddle.net/j6qJp/1/

It may be useful for somebody. Thanks

Comment: Can someone explain why this is better than the answer that @Aleross provides below? It is not immediately clear what it does versus the pad function which is explicitly clear.

Comment: Simpler, just use myDate.toISOString() which has leading zeros. Parse out relevant parts using substring.

Comment: @n00b I agree. This is longer and seems like an overkill. Also, it looks worse in terms of performance (calling `slice` following a concatenation looks more expensive than a simple string concatenation following a comparison), but I am not a computer science graduate or anything like that. It is a creative solution, indeed, but nothing more than that, I think.

Comment: Way clever.  Works fine for short, quick strings.  Probably want to do something more performant if you were processing a lot of them.  In a dragging display scenario, dragging and formatting across several date/time ticks and displaying them on the fly in a moving window - works just fine.

Comment: Not to mention that today this example gave me 26/06/2014  instead of 06/06/2014

Comment: @DazManCat: That's what it is supposed to do. The code starts by adding 20 days to the current date. `MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate() + 20);`

Comment: @n00b I suppose it's not necessarily better, just more popular. I'm guessing if they are put side-by-side, it would be because of the additional private function required to perform the pad.

Comment: @n00b and @Phil Cooper, without getting hung up on a discussion about the ins and outs of timing JavaScript routines, I found that the `slice()` technique in the accepted answer is about a 1/10 of a second faster than @Aleross 's  `pad()` technique on 1 million iterations. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ej4bb0oL/). "pay your money, take your pick".

Comment: `function pad(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2);}`

Comment: @claudio because there's no need to declare a function.

Answer (score 293):

### The modern way

The new modern way to do this is to use [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), because it allows you not only to format a date with proper localization, but even to pass format options to achieve the desired result:

```js
const date = new Date(2018, 2, 1)
const result = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", { // you can use undefined as first argument
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "2-digit",
})
console.log(result) // outputs “01/03/2018”
```

Or using a Temporal object (**[still in proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/)**, [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/temporal)):

```
const date = new Temporal.PlainDate(2018, 3, 1) // also works with zoned date
const result = date.toLocaleString("en-GB", { // you can use undefined as first argument
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "2-digit",
})
console.log(result) // outputs “01/03/2018”
```

When you use `undefined` as the first argument it will detect the browser language, instead. Alternatively, you can use `2-digit` on the year option, too.

#### Performance

If you plan to format a lot of dates, you should consider using [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) instead:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", { // <- re-use me
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "2-digit",
})
const date = new Date(2018, 2, 1) // can also be a Temporal object
const result = formatter.format(date)
console.log(result) // outputs “01/03/2018”
```

The formatter is compatible with Date and Temporal objects.

#### Historical dates

Unlike in the Temporal constructor years between 0 and 99 will be interpreted as 20th century years on the Date constructor. To prevent this, initialize the date like so:

```js
const date = new Date()
date.setFullYear(18, 2, 1) // the year is A.D. 18
```

This is not required for Temporal objects, but years below 1000 will not contain leading zeros in all cases, because the formatter (that is shared for the Date and Temporal API) does not support `4-digit` formatting at all. In this case you have to do manual formatting (see below).

### For the ISO 8601 format

If you want to get your date in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format (ISO 8601), the solution looks different:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 2, 1))
const result = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
console.log(result) // outputs “2018-03-01”
```

Your input date should be in the UTC format or `toISOString()` will fix that for you. This is done by using `Date.UTC` as shown above.

#### Historical dates for the ISO 8601 format

Unlike in the Temporal constructor years between 0 and 99 will be interpreted as 20th century years on the Date constructor. To prevent this, initialize the date like so to be used for the ISO 8601 format:

```js
const date = new Date()
date.setUTCFullYear(18, 2, 1) // the year is A.D. 18
```

Note that the ISO format for Temporal objects with dates before the year 1000 or after the year 9999 will have a [different formatting](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/blob/04ecd9884600a93637b37e50bea834a46261e69b/polyfill/lib/ecmascript.mjs#L1966-L1976) compared to the legacy Date API. It is recommend to fallback to custom formatting to enforce 4 digit years in all circumstances.

### Custom 4-digit formatting on the year

Sadly, the formatter doesn't support leading zeros on the year. There is no `4-digit` option. This will remain for Temporal objects as well, because they do share the same formatter.

Fortunately, the ISO format of the Date API will always display at least 4 digits on the year, although Temporal objects do not. So at least for the Date API you can format historical dates before the year 1000 with leading zeros by falling back to a manual formatting approach using part of the ISO 8601 format method:

```js
const date = new Date()
date.setUTCFullYear(18, 2, 1)
const ymd = date.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-')
const result = `${ymd[2]}/${ymd[1]}/${ymd[0]}`
console.log(result) // outputs “01/03/0018”
```

For a Temporal object a different route is necessary, since the `ISOYearString` [will be formatted differently for dates before the year 1000 and after the year 9999](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/blob/04ecd9884600a93637b37e50bea834a46261e69b/polyfill/lib/ecmascript.mjs#L1966-L1976) as mentioned before:

```
const date = new Temporal.PlainDate(2018, 3, 1) // also works with zoned date
const zeroPad = (n, digits) => n.toString().padStart(digits, '0');
const result = `${zeroPad(date.day, 2)}/${zeroPad(date.month, 2)}/${zeroPad(date.year, 4)}`;
console.log(result) // outputs “01/03/0018”
```

### Miscellaneous

For the Date and Temporal API there is also [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), that allows you to localize and format the time of a date.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. More info about the options available for toLocaleDateString here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: @JoseLinares Hi, thanks for putting this link back in the days. I just decided to improve my answer to make the solution more appealing for common scenarios, since you can skip the first argument and IE10 is not relevant anymore. With that in mind, I included your link into my answer.

Comment: @modiX, sorry it was a my mistake in code and i took wrong way the description, Yes the *locales* (first variable) is *Optional*.

Comment: How to add leading zeros to the year using this method ? `year: "numeric"` displays the year as is, not on 4 digits :(

Comment: @Sixteen Unfortunately, there is no `4-digit` format option to address historical dates below the year 1000 with the modern approach. I updated my answer to address your issue and provide an alternative solution for this case. I wish there was a better way to do this, though.

Answer (score 128):

Here is an example from the [Date object docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Example.3A_ISO_8601_formatted_dates) on the Mozilla Developer Network using a custom "pad" function, without having to extend Javascript's Number prototype. The handy function they give as an example is

```
function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
```

And below is it being used in context.

```
/* use a function for the exact format desired... */
function ISODateString(d){
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
    + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
    + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
    + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
    + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
    + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(ISODateString(d)); // prints something like 2009-09-28T19:03:12Z
```

Comment: Very nice way of doing it. I think the accepted answer is really nice, but this even cleaner in my opinion

Comment: this could lead to unexpected bugs cause it outputs a string for < 10 and a number for >= 10

Comment: @DavidFregoli, all those date to string functions return a string, so if you input a string, `pad` does output only strings.

Answer (score 86):

## For you people from the future (ECMAScript 2017 and beyond)

### Solution

```
"use strict"

const today = new Date()

const year = today.getFullYear()

const month = `${today.getMonth() + 1}`.padStart(2, "0")

const day = `${today.getDate()}`.padStart(2, "0")

const stringDate = [day, month, year].join("/") // 13/12/2017
```

### Explaination

the [`String.prototype.padStart(targetLength[, padString])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) adds as many as possible `padString` in the `String.prototype` target so that the new length of the target is `targetLength`.

#### Example

```
"use strict"

let month = "9"

month = month.padStart(2, "0") // "09"

let byte = "00000100"

byte = byte.padStart(8, "0") // "00000100"
```

Comment: This is part of ES2017 or ES8. So it's incorrect to say "ES6+" as it's not part of ES6 and ES7.

Comment: This should technically be `.padStart(2, '0')` since the second parameter is a string, although it probably won't matter unless you're using TypeScript

Comment: This solution is really elegant.

Answer (score 58):

You can define a "str_pad" function (as in php):

```
function str_pad(n) {
    return String("00" + n).slice(-2);
}
```

Comment: "0" instead of "00" is enough

Answer (score 19):

I found the shorterst way to do this:

```
 MyDateString.replace(/(^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, '$10$2');
```

will add leading zeros to all lonely, single digits

Comment: I like this solution, can you maybe clarifiy a bit what happens there?

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? Seems like an elegant solution

Comment: Regexp finds maximum of three groups:
$1 - any non-digit symbol (or beginning of the line)
$2 - any digit
$3 - any non-digit (that may not exist)

Then we're replacing the captured (matched) stuff with
$1 + "0" + $2 which comes $10$2 in the replacement string.

Comment: It finds a single digit (between any other symbols) and adds a zero before this single digit
You can play with
S = ['1/2/16', '2.10.20', '3 5 9', 'Today is 4.5.20', 'US style 3/9/21'];

S.forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/(^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, '$10$2')))

Comment: `$3` does **not** exist in your regex, `(?!\d)` is **negative lookahead** not to add the leading zero if there is more than one digit.

Answer (score 12):

```
Number.prototype.padZero= function(len){
 var s= String(this), c= '0';
 len= len || 2;
 while(s.length < len) s= c + s;
 return s;
}
```

//in use:

```
(function(){
 var myDate= new Date(), myDateString;
 myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+10);

 myDateString= [myDate.getDate().padZero(),
 (myDate.getMonth()+1).padZero(),
 myDate.getFullYear()].join('/');

 alert(myDateString);
})()

/*  value: (String)
09/09/2010
*/
```

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays you can also utilize [String.prototype.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to reach the goal in quick and easy way

```
String(new Date().getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
```

The availability can be assessed at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_padstart)

```
var date = new Date()

var year = date.getFullYear()
var month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
var day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')

console.log('%s/%s/%s', month, day, year)
```

Check

```js
var date = new Date('7/4/2021')
    
var year = date.getFullYear()
var month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
var day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')
    
/**
 * Expected output: 07/04/2021
 */
console.log('%s/%s/%s', month, day, year)
```

Polyfill for old browsers

```
String.prototype.padStart || Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'padStart', {
    configurable : true,
    writable : true,
    value : function (targetLength, padString) {
        'use strict'
        /**
         * String.prototype.padStart polyfill
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date
         */
        targetLength = targetLength | 0
        padString = arguments.length > 1 ? String(padString) : ' '

        if (this.length < targetLength && padString.length) {
            targetLength = targetLength - this.length

            while (padString.length < targetLength) {
                padString += padString
            }

            return padString.slice(0, targetLength) + this
        } else {
            return this
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var MyDate = new Date();
var MyDateString = '';
MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate());
var tempoMonth = (MyDate.getMonth()+1);
var tempoDate = (MyDate.getDate());
if (tempoMonth < 10) tempoMonth = '0' + tempoMonth;
if (tempoDate < 10) tempoDate = '0' + tempoDate;
MyDateString = tempoDate + '/' + tempoMonth + '/' + MyDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 8):

There is another approach to solve this problem, using `slice` in JavaScript.

```
var d = new Date();
var datestring = d.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"-"+("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

the `datestring` return date with format as you expect: 2019-09-01

another approach is using `dateformat` library: https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat

Comment: Take care in spelling "JavaScript".

Answer (score 6):

You could use ternary operator to format the date like an "if" statement.

For example:

```
var MyDate = new Date();
MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate()+10);
var MyDateString = (MyDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + MyDate.getDate() : MyDate.getDate()) + '/' + ((d.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0' + (d.getMonth()+1) : (d.getMonth()+1)) + '/' + MyDate.getFullYear();
```

So

```
(MyDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + MyDate.getDate() : MyDate.getDate())
```

would be similar to an if statement, where if the getDate() returns a value less than 10, then return a '0' + the Date, or else return the date if greater than 10 (since we do not need to add the leading 0).  Same for the month.

Edit:
Forgot that getMonth starts with 0, so added the +1 to account for it.  Of course you could also just say d.getMonth() < 9 :, but I figured using the +1 would help make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

```
function formatDate(jsDate){
  // add leading zeroes to jsDate when days or months are < 10.. 
  // i.e.
  //     formatDate(new Date("1/3/2013")); 
  // returns
  //    "01/03/2103"
  ////////////////////
  return (jsDate.getDate()<10?("0"+jsDate.getDate()):jsDate.getDate()) + "/" + 
      ((jsDate.getMonth()+1)<10?("0"+(jsDate.getMonth()+1)):(jsDate.getMonth()+1)) + "/" + 
      jsDate.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can provide options as a parameter to format date. First parameter is for locale which you might not need and second is for options.
For more info visit 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0));
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString(undefined,options));
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrapped the correct answer of this question in a function that can add multiple leading zero's but defaults to adding 1 zero.

```
function zeroFill(nr, depth){
  depth = (depth === undefined)? 1 : depth;

  var zero = "0";
  for (var i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
    zero += "0";
  }

  return (zero + nr).slice(-(depth + 1));
}
```

for working with numbers only and not more than 2 digits, this is also an approach:

```
function zeroFill(i) {
    return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to @modiX answer, this is what works...DO NOT LEAVE THAT as empty

```
today.toLocaleDateString("default", {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using a built-in function to do the padding (but resulting in quite long code!):

```
myDateString = myDate.getDate().toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})
  + '/' + (myDate.getMonth()+1).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})
  + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();

// '12/06/2017'
```

And another, manipulating strings with regular expressions:

```
var myDateString = myDate.toISOString().replace(/T.*/, '').replace(/-/g, '/');

// '2017/06/12'
```

But be aware that one will show the year at the *start* and the day at the *end*.

Comment: liked this the most :  myDate.getDate().toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})

Answer (score 2):

Here is very simple example how you can handle this situation.

```js
var mydate = new Date();

var month = (mydate.getMonth().toString().length < 2 ? "0"+mydate.getMonth().toString() :mydate.getMonth());

var date = (mydate.getDate().toString().length < 2 ? "0"+mydate.getDate().toString() :mydate.getDate());

var year = mydate.getFullYear();

console.log("Format Y-m-d : ",year+"-"+month+"-" + date);

console.log("Format Y/m/d : ",year+"/"+month+"/" + date);
```

Comment: And you missed the +1 for the month

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution is easier and can be easily remembered:

```js
var MyDate = new Date();


var day = MyDate.getDate() + 10; // 10 days in advance
var month = MyDate.getMonth() + 1; // since months start from 0 we should add 1 to it
var year = MyDate.getFullYear();

day = checkDate(day);
month = checkDate(month);


function checkDate(i){
    if(i < 10){
    i = '0' + i;
  }
  return i;
}

console.log(`${month}/${day}/${year}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is create my own custom Date helper that looks like this :

```js
var DateHelper = {
    addDays : function(aDate, numberOfDays) {
        aDate.setDate(aDate.getDate() + numberOfDays); // Add numberOfDays
        return aDate;                                  // Return the date
    },
    format : function format(date) {
        return [
           ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2),           // Get day and pad it with zeroes
           ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),      // Get month and pad it with zeroes
           date.getFullYear()                          // Get full year
        ].join('/');                                   // Glue the pieces together
    }
}

// With this helper, you can now just use one line of readable code to :
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1. Get the current date
// 2. Add 20 days
// 3. Format it
// 4. Output it
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
document.body.innerHTML = DateHelper.format(DateHelper.addDays(new Date(), 20));
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9fpzcghg/1/))

Answer (score 1):

As @John Henckel suggests, starting using the [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method makes things easier

```js
const dateString = new Date().toISOString().split('-');
const year = dateString[0];
const month = dateString[1];
const day = dateString[2].split('T')[0];

console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for a basic function, no libraries required

```
Date.prototype.CustomformatDate = function() {
 var tmp = new Date(this.valueOf());
 var mm = tmp.getMonth() + 1;
 if (mm < 10) mm = "0" + mm;
 var dd = tmp.getDate();
 if (dd < 10) dd = "0" + dd;
 return mm + "/" + dd + "/" + tmp.getFullYear();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) which extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string:

```js
const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10) // 2020-04-16
```

Or you can also use a lib such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to format the date:

```js
const moment = require("moment")
const currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") // 2020-04-16
```

Answer (score 1):

## ***You could simply use :***

```
const d = new Date();
const day = `0${d.getDate()}`.slice(-2);
```

So a function could be created like :

```
AddZero(val){
    // adding 0 if the value is a single digit
    return `0${val}`.slice(-2);
}
```

Your new code :

```
var MyDate = new Date();
var MyDateString = new Date();

MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate()+10);
MyDateString = AddZero(MyDate.getDate()) + '/' + AddZero(MyDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + MyDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

toISOString can get leading 0

```js
    const currentdate = new Date(); 
    const date = new Date(Date.UTC(currentdate.getFullYear(), (currentdate.getMonth()),currentdate.getDate(), currentdate.getHours(), currentdate.getMinutes(), currentdate.getSeconds()));
    //you can pass YY, MM, DD //op: 2018-03-01
    //i have passed YY, MM, DD, HH, Min, Sec // op : 2021-06-09T12:14:27.000Z
    console.log(date.toISOString());
```

output will be similar to this : 2021-06-09T12:14:27.000Z

Answer (score 1):

```
const month = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { month: '2-digit' });
const day = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: '2-digit' });
const year = date.getFullYear();
const dateString = `${month}-${day}-${year}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following aims to extract configuration, hook into `Date.protoype` and apply configuration.

I've used an `Array` to store time chunks and when I `push()` `this` as a `Date` object, it returns me the length to iterate. When I'm done, I can use `join` on the `return` value.

This seems to work pretty fast: 0.016ms

```
// Date protoype
Date.prototype.formatTime = function (options) {
    var i = 0,
        time = [],
        len = time.push(this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds());

    for (; i < len; i += 1) {
        var tick = time[i];
        time[i] = tick < 10 ? options.pad + tick : tick;
    }

    return time.join(options.separator);
};

// Setup output
var cfg = {
    fieldClock: "#fieldClock",
    options: {
        pad: "0",
        separator: ":",
        tick: 1000
    }
};

// Define functionality
function startTime() {
    var clock = $(cfg.fieldClock),
        now = new Date().formatTime(cfg.options);

    clock.val(now);
    setTimeout(startTime, cfg.options.tick);
}

// Run once
startTime();
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/U4MZ3/

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding to allow a leading zero - where needed - and concatenate using your delimiter of choice as string.

```
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
        var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
        return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
    }

var d = new Date(my_date);
var dformatted = [(d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(), d.getDate().padLeft(), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let date = new Date();
 let dd = date.getDate();//day of month

 let mm = date.getMonth();// month
 let yyyy = date.getFullYear();//day of week
 if (dd < 10) {//if less then 10 add a leading zero
     dd = "0" + dd;
   }
 if (mm < 10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;//if less then 10 add a leading zero
  }
```

Comment: you can also describe in short what you attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pad(value) {
    return value.tostring().padstart(2, 0);
}

let d = new date();
console.log(d);
console.log(`${d.getfullyear()}-${pad(d.getmonth() + 1)}-${pad(d.getdate())}t${pad(d.gethours())}:${pad(d.getminutes())}:${pad(d.getseconds())}`);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [dateformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) library saved my life ([GitHub](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat)):

- Node.js: `var dateFormat = require("dateformat");`
- ES6: `import dateFormat from "dateformat";`

```
const now = new Date();             // consider 3rd of December 1993

const full = dateFormat(today, "yyyy-mm-dd");  // 1993-12-03
const day = dateFormat(today, "dd");           // 03
const month = dateFormat(today, "mm");         // 12
const year = dateFormat(today, "yyyy");        // 1993
```

It's worth to mention it supports a wide range of mask options.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest version I can think of:

```js
const addZero = (val: number) => (val < 10 ? "0" + val : val);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update for 2023

If you are looking for a simple modern solution, date-fns handles this beautifully.

### Usage

```
import {format} from 'date-fns';

const myDate = new Date();
const formattedDate = format(myDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Comment: ! But you have to use an extra lib: https://date-fns.org/

Answer (score 0):

For custom formatting and historical dates - building on the answer by Martin Braun - using the Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor method 'formatToParts' it is easy to manually tweak the formatting before returning.

The following manipulates the year to ensure it always returns 4-digits.

```js
const date = new Date();

new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
}).formatToParts(date).map((obj) => {
    if (obj.type === 'year') {
      return obj.value.padStart(4, '0');
    }
    return obj.value;
  }).join('')
```