# Javascript date - Leading 0 for days and months where applicable

Tags: javascript, date

Is there a clean way of adding a 0 in front of the day or month when the day or month is less than 10:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var prettyDate =(myDate.getFullYear() +'-'+ myDate.getMonth()) +'-'+ myDate.getDate();
```

This would output as:

```
2011-8-8
```

I would like it to be:

```
2011-08-08
```

Comment: Double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date

Comment: Check out the datejs library: http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 30):

The format you seem to want looks like ISO. So take advantage of `toISOString()`:

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.toISOString().slice(0,10); // "2014-05-12"
```

Comment: The best answer

Comment: It can be somewhat shortened: `(new Date()).toISOString().slice(0,10);`, but still the best answer.

Answer (score 23):

No, there is no nice way to do it. You have to resort to something like:

```
var myDate = new Date();

var year = myDate.getFullYear();

var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
if(month <= 9)
    month = '0'+month;

var day= myDate.getDate();
if(day <= 9)
    day = '0'+day;

var prettyDate = year +'-'+ month +'-'+ day;
```

Comment: Months are zero-indexed in `Date`, so this would shift any month down by one notch (as well as create invalid dates in the case of january).

Answer (score 8):

```
var myDate = new Date();
var m = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
var d = myDate.getDate();
m = m > 9 ? m : "0"+m;
d = d > 9 ? d : "0"+d;
var prettyDate =(myDate.getFullYear() +'-'+ m) +'-'+ d;
```

...and a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gFkaP/

Answer (score 6):

You can try like this

For day:

```
("0" + new Date().getDate()).slice(-2)
```

For month:

```
("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
```

For year:

```
new Date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to manually check if it needs a leading zero and add it if necessary...

```
var m = myDate.getMonth();
var d =  myDate.getDate();

if (m < 10) {
    m = '0' + m
}

if (d < 10) {
    d = '0' + d
}

var prettyDate = myDate.getFullYear() +'-'+ m +'-'+ d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, get [`String.js`](http://code.google.com/p/jsxt/) by Rumata and then use:

```
'%04d-%02d-%02d'.sprintf(myDate.getFullYear(),
                         myDate.getMonth() + 1,
                         myDate.getDate());
```

NB: don't forget the `+ 1` on the month field.  The `Date` object's month field starts from zero, not one!

If you don't want to use an extra library, a trivial inline function will do the job of adding the leading zeroes:

```
function date2str(d) {
    function fix2(n) {
        return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
    }
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' +
           fix2(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
           fix2(d.getDate());
 }
```

or even add it to the `Date` prototype:

```
Date.prototype.ISO8601date = function() {
    function fix2(n) {
        return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
    }
    return this.getFullYear() + '-' +
           fix2(this.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
           fix2(this.getDate());
 }
```

usage (see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/M5S5u/):

```
 var d = new Date();
 var s = d.ISO8601date();
```

Comment: best answer, using sprintf, never thought of implementing that

Comment: @lbu there's _stacks_ of useful functions in String.js, if you're doing any string manipulation at all it's worth having.

Comment: Where can I download String.js? Valid question, as the projects download page is empty.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas you need to look in the source browser - http://code.google.com/p/jsxt/source/browse/trunk/js/String.js

Answer (score 1):

For Month,
`var month = ("0" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);`

For Day,
`var day = ("0" + (myDate.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2);`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no built-in date-format in javascript. Either use a existing library (example http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) or build your own method for adding a leading zero.

```
var addLeadingZeroIfNeeded = function addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(dateNumber) {
        if (String(dateNumber).length === 1) {
            return '0' + String(dateNumber);
        }

        return String(dateNumber);
    },
    myDate = new Date(),
    prettyDate;

prettyDate = myDate.getFullYear() + '-' + addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(myDate.getMonth()) + '-' + addLeadingZeroIfNeeded(myDate.getDate());
```

**EDIT**

As Alnitak said, keep in mind that month i JavaScript starts on 0 not 1.

Comment: your code won't work - numbers don't have a `.length` property.

Comment: I get an incorrect month, and twice as much source code as necessary.  Compare with `date2str` in my answer.

Comment: It depends of what month you pass to the method, this method is for adding a leading 0 where needed, not handle the month. Single responsibility. But I'll add it for clarification. But the twice amount of code is for readability, not optimization.

Comment: JS months start at zero, not one.  Your code (like many of the answers here, as well as the OP's code) will show the wrong number.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to prepend a `zero` and then use `.slice(-2)`.
With this function you always return the last 2 characters of a `string`.

`var month = 8;`

`var monthWithLeadingZeros = ('0' + month).slice(-2);`

Checkout this example:
http://codepen.io/Shven/pen/vLgQMQ?editors=101