# Get time from datetime in jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime

How to get time form the datetime in jquery

Suppose,

```
datetime = Wed Mar 06 2013 11:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I need only 11:30:00 from this such that

```
time = 11:30:00
```

Comment: You either split the string (which is ugly) or you only request the time as output. How do you do it now?

Comment: you want to get current time from current date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check out the [W3C Javascript Datetime Object Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp):

```
var hours = datetime.getHours(); //returns 0-23
var minutes = datetime.getMinutes(); //returns 0-59
var seconds = datetime.getSeconds(); //returns 0-59
```

your question:

```
if(minutes<10)
  minutesString = 0+minutes+""; //+""casts minutes to a string.
else
  minutesString = minutes;
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i make it to show like hh : mm : ss format.
Now when its 12 then it shows 12:0:0, i want 12:00:00.

Answer (score 5):

Try this to get the current day's current time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var cHour = today.getHours();
    var cMin = today.getMinutes();
    var cSec = today.getSeconds();
    alert(cHour+ ":" + cMin+ ":" +cSec );
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i make it to show like hh : mm : ss format.
Now when its 12 then it shows 12:0:0, i want 12:00:00.

Comment: [You can check this answer for the format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34838593/1136253)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution,

Create a Javascript Date:

```
var aDate = new Date(
    Date.parse('Wed Mar 06 2013 11:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)');
);
```

Build the output string:

```
var dateString = '';

var h = aDate.getHours();
var m = aDate.getMinutes();
var s = aDate.getSeconds();

if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
if (s < 10) s = '0' + s;

dateString = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
```

Documentation Links:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: var datetime is not a string. Date.parse expects a string.

Comment: Stuart Eske: Thanks but how can i make it to show like hh : mm : ss format. Now when its 12 then it shows 12:0:0, i want 12:00:00.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, take a look at this link.

[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979697/javascript-date-leading-0-for-days-and-months-where-applicable)

@Developer

Answer (score 1):

What about using the excellent [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do it very easily with JavaScript.

using the
[`Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR'));
// Output: "20:30:39"
```

Some locales will give you different results, this is why i used the `pt-BR` for the format (24h without AM/PM) (the timezone will stay the same, this will only change the format).
You can also use any other locale and pass `{hour12:false}` as the options.

```js
const event = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+00:00');
var options = {hour12:false}
console.log("en-US (options): " + event.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options));
console.log("en-US          : " + event.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
console.log("ar-EG (options): " + event.toLocaleTimeString('ar-EG', options));
console.log("ar-EG          : " + event.toLocaleTimeString('ar-EG'));
console.log("pt-BR (options): " + event.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', options));
console.log("pt-BR          : " + event.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR'));
/* Output: 
"en-US (options): 20:15:30"
"en-US          : 8:15:30 PM"
"ar-EG (options): ٢٠:١٥:٣٠"
"ar-EG          : ٨:١٥:٣٠ م"
"pt-BR (options): 20:15:30"
"pt-BR          : 20:15:30"
*/
```