# How to add leading zero to the jQueryUI Datepicker (inside code, not output)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a calendar from jQueryUI datepicker.

For a some reason I would like to know, how to change a

```
data-month='" + printDate.getMonth() + "'
```

to show current month with a leading zero, if it has it.

We may see this code (as a ready HTML) at a calendar's row:

```
<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2013">
    <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a>
</td>
```

So, now it is a September, so it should shows a '09' instead of '8'

To make it '9' I did `+ (printDate.getMonth()+1) +`

But I have no idea how to make it with a ZERO.

It should be something like

```
if(printDate.getMonth() < 10){printDate.getMonth() = '0'+printDate.getMonth()}
```

But this code does not work, I'm sure I did something wrong with it.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/a/6979773/804087

Comment: while adding zero to printDate.getMonth() its converted to string, because of this its showing ReferenceError you need to use parseInt before assigning to it again

Answer (score 0):

printDate.getMonth() is getter. You need to use setter or if there is not any store it in local variable for further use.

```
var monthString = printDate.getMonth();
if(printDate.getMonth() < 10){
    monthString= '0'+ printDate.getMonth();
}
```

And when generating HTML:

```
data-month='" + monthString + "'
```