# How to change date output format

Tags: javascript, date

I am developing a system about Allowance in PHP, MySQL and it should calculate the **last date employee** to receive their allowance. This is my JavaScript to calculate the last date. Output for below code is **15-7-2015**. 
I would like it to be **15-07-2015**.

What should I change to get output like that ?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateLast() {

 var x = document.form1.tempoh.value; //<-----------Tempoh Elaun
    var CurrentDate = new Date();
    CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + eval(x));

    var day = CurrentDate.getDate();
    var monthIndex = CurrentDate.getMonth()+1;
    var year = CurrentDate.getFullYear();

 document.getElementById('tamatElaun').value = day + "-" + monthIndex + "-" + year;
    //document.write(day, monthNames[monthIndex], year);
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Month and Date of JavaScript in 2 digit format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040515/how-do-i-get-month-and-date-of-javascript-in-2-digit-format) OR [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date) OR [Javascript date - Leading 0 for days and months where applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979697/javascript-date-leading-0-for-days-and-months-where-applicable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
function calculateLast() {

    var x = document.form1.tempoh.value; //<-----------Tempoh Elaun
    var CurrentDate = new Date();
    CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + eval(x));

    var day = CurrentDate.getDate();
    var monthIndex = ("0" + (CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var year = CurrentDate.getFullYear();

    document.getElementById('tamatElaun').value = day + "-" + monthIndex + "-" + year;
    //document.write(day, monthNames[monthIndex], year);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    var today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
    document.getElementById("tamatElaun").value = today;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code

```js
var CurrentDate = new Date('2015-7-15');
var listMonths = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
var day = CurrentDate.getDate();
var monthIndex = CurrentDate.getMonth();
var year = CurrentDate.getFullYear();
alert(day + '/' + listMonths[monthIndex] + '/' + year);
```

You can also change **listMonths** into array of string, ex: ['Jan', 'Feb', ..., 'Dec']

Answer (score 0):

```
 var CurrentDate = new Date();
    CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth());

    var day = CurrentDate.getDate();
    var monthIndex = CurrentDate.getMonth()+1;
    if(monthIndex<10){
        monthIndex=('0'+monthIndex);
    }
    var year = CurrentDate.getFullYear();
    alert(monthIndex);
    //document.getElementById('tamatElaun').value = day + "-" + monthIndex + "-" + year;
    });
```

Comment: only add this code.    if(monthIndex<10){
        monthIndex=('0'+monthIndex);
    }