# Format Date in dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date)

It might be a simple question because I am still *newbie* in JavaScript, assume I have DateTime in ISO format:

```
 2012-07-07T17:00:00
```

I would like to format this date to string:

```
 07.07.2012
```

I have written a function to format to 7.7.2012 as below:

```
var formatDate = function (datum) {
    var date = new Date(datum);
    return date.getDate() + '.' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + date.getFullYear();
};
```

How can I modify this code to get the result `07.07.2012` instead of `7.7.2012`

Comment: [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date)

Comment: So many [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+Format+Date+in+dd.MM.yyyy)...

Comment: do you plan to use jquery as well? will you be doing any formatting more fancy than above? (eg: 5 seconds ago)

Comment: @MasonBryant: jQuery is still okay for me

Answer (score 6):

This might be helpful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var date=new Date();
    day=date.getDate();
    month=date.getMonth();
    month=month+1;
    if((String(day)).length==1)
    day='0'+day;
    if((String(month)).length==1)
    month='0'+month;

    dateT=day+ '.' + month + '.' + date.getFullYear();
    //dateT=String(dateT);
    alert(dateT);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at this

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Its the best I found, and it also has a host of other useful functions.

Comment: [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is recommended these days (more modular, modern syntax, actively maintained)

Comment: Or [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) if you want to stay close to the moment API without the huge footprint.

Answer (score 1):

use this handy script. The link provides instructions

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format