# Format a time string with zero based hours and minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

This is what have tried:

partly pseudocode:

```
var hours = date1.getHours();
var minutes = date2.getMinutes();

if (hours.length == 1)
    hours = "0" + hours;

if (minutes.length == 1)
    minutes = "0" + minutes;

var time = hours + ':' + minutes;
```

Is there a smarter way like a formatted string function where I can say:

```
var minutes = date.getMinutes('mm');
var hours = date.getHours('hh');
```

so it adds the zeros automatically ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality doesn't exist natively in javascript, you have to either add it yourself (as you have started to do), or, use a package.

- [moment](http://momentjs.com/)
- [Mozilla has an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [Here's a blog post to a date formatting function](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)
- [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)
- [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

Comment: Love moments, a great and uncomplicated little date library.

Comment: I did install moment.js now and got rid of 15 redundant lines of code replaced by 3 lines with better readability. I love moment from the very first moment...

Answer (score 5):

Here is your code fixed since there is no length on an integer

```
var hours = date1.getHours();
var minutes = date2.getMinutes();

if (hours<10) hours = "0" + hours;
if (minutes<10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

var time = ""+ hours + ":" + minutes;
```

You do not need a framework and there is no shorter way to do this

This may be what you mean:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/337yj/)

```
function pad(num) {
  return ("0"+num).slice(-2)
}
var time = pad(date1.getHours())+":"+pad(date2.getMinutes());
```

Comment: Love the specific pad solution, "("0"+num).slice(-2)"

Comment: It could be more general, but that would sort of defeat the purpose of keeping it short. For hours, minutes and seconds we only need max two chars

Answer (score 2):

Use DateJS and you will be able to use mm and hh to add the preceding zeros :)

https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Comment: Why the down vote? Some kind of conflict between Datejs and moment users?

Comment: moment sounds much more l33t ;P

Comment: Check this out : http://jsperf.com/underscore-date-vs-datejs/7
Quote :
moment.js is lighter, and offers much faster parsing. On the other hand, date.js offers much faster formatting and manipulation. As the user is looking for formatting, I stick to my answer : DateJS rulez!

Comment: its a shame that I have to use a library for such a common task... @xShirase If I would want speed I would not choose javascript ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method to Number prototype

```
  Number.prototype.pad0 = function(length) {
    var result = this.toString();
    while(result.length<length) result = "0"+result;
    return result;
  }
```

Then you can get what you want

```
  var date = new Date();  
  console.log(date.getMinutes().pad0(2));
  console.log(date.getHours().pad0(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way of doing it:

```
var d = new Date();
var t = [ d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds() ];

var s = t.map( function(z){return ('00'+z).slice(-2)} ).join(':');

console.log(s);
```

Time parts are put into an array. That array goes through `map()` where the numbers get leading zeros. The resulting array is then joined into a string with the ":" separator.

Answer (score 0):

Convert numbers to strings before you check the lengths:

```
var hours = String(date1.getHours());
var minutes = String(date2.getMinutes());

if (hours.length == 1)
    hours = "0" + hours;

if (minutes.length == 1)
    minutes = "0" + minutes;

var time = hours + ':' + minutes;
```

Comment: or just test they are less than 10