# change the event color of two different events of fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

i am working with full calendar and i want to apply a condition in which the appointment accepted events looking in green color and pending request appointments look in red color.
How can i apply different colors to different-2 events?

Comment: As variant you can add `status` property to your events and check it state. How you can change event bg color you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17787268/1613335)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the callback [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/), checking the properties for a specific string and changing the color through jQuery:

```
eventAfterRender: function ( event, element ) {
    console.log( event ); // Debug
    if( event.title.indexOf("Pending") > -1 ) { // if title contains "Pending"
        element.css( {'background-color': '#14B9E2', 'border': '1px solid #14B9E2'} );
    }
}
```