# toString(16) with leading zeroes

Tags: javascript

When you convert a small number to a hexadecimal representation, you need leading zeroes, because `toString(16)` will return `f` for `15`, instead of `00000f`. Usually I will use the loop like this:

```
var s = X.toString(16); while (s.length < 6) s = '0' + s
```

is there a better way in JavaScript?

UPD: The answer [suggested answer  How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)  is not what I am looking for, I look for a very short code, that is suited specifically for 24 bit integers converted to a hexadecimal looking strings.

Comment: There may be something using number formating

Comment: that answer is 8 lines of code! I am looking for something that is shorter than my ONE line

Comment: @exebook: It depends whether you need to support arbitrary-long fills, decimals, negative numbers… You can extract a useful oneliner from the answers.

Comment: Similar question: [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3605214/3096782)

Comment: x.toString(16).padStart(2,"0")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
('00000'+(15).toString(16)).substr(-5)
```

Comment: That is interesting +1

Comment: -1: [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) with negative indizes is not supported by IE. Use `slice` instead.

Comment: Also OP is looking to pad a number **`X`** to a length of **`6`**…

Comment: Cool, but ridiculous. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
var s = X.toString(16);
s = "000000".substr(0, 6 - s.length) + s;
```