# Add a Leading Zero to a Number?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, numbers

Am looking to add a leading zero to Date minutes when under 10, while keeping it a number for querying

Followed the slice technique from [javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date)

This has yet to run for some reason:

```
var datetimeNow = new Date();
var minuteNow = datetimeNow.getMinutes();
// add a leading zero
if (minuteNow < 10 ) {
    var ZeroMinuteNow = ('0' + datetimeNow.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    var minuteNow = parseInt(ZeroMinuteNow, 10);
    console.log(minuteNow);
}
```

Comment: `.toFixed()` might help

Comment: Could it be because `minuteNow` is >= 10?

Comment: To have a leading zero the object (a `number`) must become a `string`, when you `parseInt` that `string` then you convert back to a `number`, which has no leading zero.

Comment: You need to log the string and not the int.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var datetimeNow = new Date();
var minuteNow = datetimeNow.getMinutes();
// add a leading zero
if (minuteNow < 10 ) {
var muestra = ('0'+ minuteNow);
console.log(muestra);
}
```