# Updating time span with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tiny script which should update a span with the current time.

This script works BEFORE the setInterval but not during the setInterval.

HTML:

```
<?= date("d/m/Y") ?> <span id="time"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
    $("#time").text(time);
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log("interval");
        time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
        $("#time").text(time);
    },5000);
});
```

The span with id time just doesn't change the time.

Comment: i would go with moment.js or some library, this is too primitive with setInterval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `dt` each time, the date object doesn't keep updating the time. It stays at the time it was created.

See this code and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4wp3qzt/1/)

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();

$("#time").text(time);

setInterval(function(){

    dt = new Date();
    time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();

    $("#time").text(time);

},5000);
```

Comment: thnx that worked now i only gotta know how to add a leading 0 if its beneith 10 :(

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date Basically just add zero all the time then use slice to grab the last 2 characters and you always get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the `dt` object too. Your `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` functions inside work on the `dt` object initialised before the `setInterval()`.
If you do not re-init `dt` it will take the date of cached object.

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("interval");

    dt = new Date();                //here!

    time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
    console.log(time)
    $("#time").text(time);
},5000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6cubhejd/)**

---

Full code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
    $("#time").text(time);
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log("interval");
        dt = new Date();
        time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
        $("#time").text(time);
    },5000);
});
```