# Split Date.now() into parts in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to split the current date into parts and this is what I am doing

```
        var today = new Date();

        var currDay = today.getDay();
        var currMonth = today.getMonth();
        var currYear = today.getYear();
        alert(currDay + "/" + currMonth + "/" + currYear)
```

but with this I get the following result

```
        0/7/115 (output)
```

where it should be

```
        09/07/2015
```

What can I do to get the required result?

Comment: `.getFullYear()` is what you should use instead of `.getYear()`, and you'll have to [pad the numbers with zeros yourself.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @Pointy it worked...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "today.getDay()" should be "today.getDate()" since .getDay goes from 0-6 (days of the week)

```
var today = new Date();
var currDay = today.getDate();
var currMonth = today.getMonth();
var currYear = today.getFullYear();
alert(currDay + "/" + currMonth + "/" + currYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var currYear = today.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605248/2649340:

```
var today = new Date();

var output   = ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
             + ('0' + (today.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
             + today.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

getDay() gives you the day's number (0-6 for sunday to monday), month starts with 0 for january. This is how to do:

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth()+1;
var year = today.getFullYear();

if(day<10) {
    day='0'+day;
} 

if(month<10) {
    month='0'+month;
} 

today = month+'/'+day+'/'+year;
alert(today);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). It has a lot of helpful functions for time and date in JavaScript