# Get audio timeupdate in 00:00 format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using html5 audio tag in my project. everything works fine.

I need to use the timeupdate and get the value of the minutes that has passed in this format: `00:00`

Currently  I can only get that value as `0:00` with my code:

This is my code:

```
$(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
    var percent = audio.currentTime/ audio.duration * 100;

    /////Passed time////
    var mins = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
    var secs = Math.floor(audio.currentTime % 60);
    if (secs < 10) {
        secs = '0' + String(secs);
    }

    $('.Audio_passedTime').text(mins + ':' + secs);
});
```

And a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cpwv2mf/

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998822/2034850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same structure you used for the `mins`, like so:

```
$(audio).bind('timeupdate', function() {
    var percent = audio.currentTime/ audio.duration * 100;

 /////Passed time////
    var mins = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
    if (mins < 10) {
      mins = '0' + String(mins);
    }
    var secs = Math.floor(audio.currentTime % 60);
    if (secs < 10) {
      secs = '0' + String(secs);
    }

$('.Audio_passedTime').text(mins + ':' + secs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that pads numbers with 0's (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010875/2314737))

```
function zpad(n) {
  return ("0" + n).slice(-2);
}
```

and then use it to format both minutes and seconds

```
$('.Audio_passedTime').text(zpad(mins) + ':' + zpad(secs));
```