# Output YYYY-MM-DD not full date string

Tags: javascript, angular, date, angular-ngmodel, ngx-bootstrap

I want to update a date linked by ngModel, using ngx-bootstrap datepicker, then send it in a PUT request to my Django backend. But the date format keeps getting changed from YYYY-MM-DD (2019-08-13) to the full javascript datestring (2019-08-13T23:00:00.000Z) which wont let me send the PUT request then.

I have tried nearly everything I can find on all other problems and it just doesnt work, nothing will let me select it as YYYY-MM-DD and keep it that way in the PUT request. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<input class="form-control" 
#dp="bsDatepicker" 
bsDatepicker
[(ngModel)]="project.Start_Date2"
name="Start_Date2" 
[bsConfig]="{
    dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    isAnimated: true, 
    containerClass: 'theme-default' 
}">
```

I just want to be able to send my PUT request with the date format as YYYY-MM-DD. I am not sure if ngx-bootstrap will do it because when I pick a date with it, it converts it to the long string which then doesn't work in the PUT request.

Comment: The datepicker assigns the ngModel with a date object. You need to format the date manually to create a string formatted as per your requirements.

Comment: Where would I format this manually but still have the good UI of the datepicker is what I'm asking really I guess?

Comment: You can use a library such as MomentJS to manually format the date object. You need to format the date before calling your API.

Comment: so if I have a (click) which calls the update function and the API then I should format the date in there?

Comment: Yes, before sending it to the API, you need to format.

Comment: And then just set the project.Start_Date to the formatted version in the update method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the date format keeps getting reverted is precisely because you use the ngModel, ie. two-way binding. The ngx-datepicker keeps pushing the selected value to your bound variable (Start_Date2). That is alright and expected.

I don't know how you do your PUT request, but you're going to need to do your format conversion either on the fly inside the request function or introduce another variable which will hold your date with the desired format.

I assume you use the angular HttpClient and the put request looks something like

```
this.http.put('https://example.com/dates/1', project.Start_Date2)
```

So what you can do is create a conversion function and convert the format inside the put call.

```
function myDateFormatFunction(inputDate) {
  let d = new Date(inputDate) // this might not be needed if the date is already a Date() object
  // YYYY-MM-DD
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2); // the zeroes and slice weirdness is to have nice padding, borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605248/3158815
}

this.http.put('https://example.com/dates/1', myDateFormatFunction(project.Start_Date2))
```

Comment: thank you very much! I have been trying to solve this issue all day, you've made it very simple for me!

Comment: actually, it does now work but it gives the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'`. My code is `project.Start_Date = myDateFormatFunction(project.Start_Date);`. `project` is then used: `this.projectService.updateProject(project).subscribe();`. Which is then used in the service with `var httpudpdate: any = this.http.put('/ph/projects/'+project.id+'/', project)`

Comment: Is the project.Start_Date also bound to a datepicker? Apparently project.Start_Date is declared as Date object.
In other words - in the myDateFormatFunction, the input variable is of type Date, while the return value is of type string.
You cannot assign the returned value back to project.Start_Date as they are different types.
You can introduce another variable (Date) and bind the datepicker to it, and project.Start_Date would be a string