# JS Date is not starting with leading 0 - Possible duplicate question

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert my array from this format

```
ka_layers2 = ["1-05-2019","2-05-2019" ........,"15-05-2019",.."27-05-2019"]
```

to something like this,

```
"01-05-2019","02-05-2019"
```

And here is my code to do so

```
for(i = 0; i < ka_layers2.length; i++){
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  var d = new Date(ka_layers2[i]);
  var day = console.log("0"+d.getDate()).slice(-2);
  console.log(day);
  ka_layers2arr.push(day + '-' + months[d.getUTCMonth()] + '-' + d.getUTCFullYear());
}
```

But this giving me a problem with `"Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"`

I'm trying with answer mentioned in this question.
[Javascript add leading zeroes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date)

Comment: Why are you calling the `slice` method on `console.log` instead of an instance of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `regex`

`/\b(\d)\b/g` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TvDPM6/2)

```js
let dates = ["1-05-2019", "2-05-2019", "15-05-2019", "27-05-2019"]

let result = dates.map(date => date.replace(/\b(\d)\b/g, '0$1'))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string, pad the parts with the wanted zeros and join the parts back to a single string.

```js
var array = ["1-05-2019", "2-05-2019", "15-5-200", "27-05-2019"],
    result = array.map(s => s.split('-').map((v, i) => v.padStart([2, 2, 4][i], '0')).join('-'));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on `-` and check if the length of first part is less than 2 than add a leading zero else keep it as it is, and than join with `-`

```js
let arr = ["1-05-2019", "2-05-2019", "15-05-2019", "27-05-2019"]

let getYearsWithZero = (str) => {
  let [date, ...rest] = str.split('-')
  date = date.length < 2 ? '0' + date : date
  return [date, ...rest].join('-')
}

arr.forEach(v => console.log(getYearsWithZero(v)))
```

---

One more way is to use replace

```js
let arr = ["1-05-2019", "2-05-2019", "15-05-2019", "27-05-2019"]

let getYearsWithZero = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/^([^-]+)/, (m, g1) => g1.length < 2 ? "0" + g1 : g1)
}

arr.forEach(v => console.log(getYearsWithZero(v)))
```

***Note:-*** The above method just changes the date, if you need the same functionality for all the parts of date you can extend accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
ka_layers2 = ["1-05-2019","2-05-2019", "15-05-2019", "27-05-2019"];

for(i = 0; i < ka_layers2.length; i++){
  if (ka_layers2[i].indexOf("-") === 1) {
    ka_layers2[i] = "0" + ka_layers2[i];
  }
}

console.log(ka_layers2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the answers. I also tried something like this and it worked.

```
for(i = 0; i < ka_layers2.length; i++){
        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
        var d = new Date(ka_layers2[i]);
        var day = "0"+d.getDate()
        var new_day =  day.slice(-2);
        ka_layers2arr.push(new_day + '-' + months[d.getUTCMonth()] + '-' + d.getUTCFullYear());
       }
```