# Javascript getDate methods with 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var monthday = d.getDate();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();
var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

date[0].innerHTML = [month + 1] + "." + monthday + " " + hours + ":" + minute;
```

This is printing the current date like this: `9.1 3:31` ...
and I want to format like this: `09.01 03:31`
Any idea how can I do that in the shortest code?

Comment: Wouldn't you want the most understandable and maintainable code, rather than the shortest code?

Comment: Here is one more :) ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date

Comment: I suggest you use https://momentjs.com/, it really helps with Dates and formatting and it's really lightweight!

Answer (score 1):

`Add` for every value before the string `"0"` and get with `slice(-2)` the last 2 chars.

```js
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var monthday = d.getDate();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();

var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

let res = '0'+[month + 1].slice(-2) + "." + ('0'+monthday).slice(-2) + ". " + ('0'+hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0'+minute).slice(-2) ;

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padStart` method:

```
 date[0].innerHTML = String([month + 1]).padStart(2, '0') + "." + String(monthday).padStart(2, '0') + " " + hour + ":" + minute ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var monthday = d.getDate();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minute = d.getMinutes();

    var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

    function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }

    date[0].innerHTML = pad([month + 1]) + "." + pad(monthday) + " " + pad(hour) + ":" + pad(minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution you can create pad to do so

### Example

```js
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var monthday = d.getDate();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();
var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
var pad = "00";
var n = `${monthday}`;
date[0].innerHTML = [month + 1] + "." + (pad + n).slice(-pad.length) + " " + hours + ":" + minute;
```

```html
<div class="date"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var monthday = d.getDate();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minute = d.getMinutes();

    var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
    let format= (number) => {
        if(number<10) {   
           return 0 + number.toString();
        }
        return number;
    }
    date[0].innerHTML = format(month + 1) + "." + format(monthday) + " " + format(hour) + ":" + format(minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple function for this particular case:

```
function formatNumber(num) { return num < 10 ? '0' + num : num; }
```

Like this:

```
console.log(formatNumber([month + 1]) + "." + formatNumber(monthday) + " " + formatNumber(hours) + ":" + formatNumber(minute));
```

Answer (score 0):

**if u are using angular make use of the date pipe**

```
var d = new Date();
```

in your html

```
{{d | date:'medium'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) or you can use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log("toLocaleDateString and  toLocaleTimeString example result: ");
console.log(     
  date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit'
  }).replace(/\//g, '.') + " " + date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit'
  })
);
console.log("toLocaleString example result: ");
console.log( 
  date.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit'
  }).replace(/\//g, '.').replace(/,/g, '')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with an external lib for this, do check out [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). This provides you with greater flexibility when you want to play with different date/time formats.

Solving your problem **the moment way** (though appreciate other posted raw solutions):

```js
console.log(moment().format('MM.DD hh:mm')); // "09.01 06:22"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```