# Why is path variable losing characters?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have an API path where I need to have dates where the month is displayed as 2 digits.  However, it keeps removing the zero to the left.

For example, when I get the date, if it's Jan through Sept, it only returns 1 digit.  So I used the following code to add the extra zero:

```
const date = new Date();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  let path = ``;
  switch (month) {
    case (month < 10):
      month = `0${month}`;
      path = `/v2/reports/time/team?from=${year}0${month}01&to=${year}0${month}31`;
      break;
    default:
      path = `/v2/reports/time/team?from=${year}${month}01&to=${year}${month}31`;
      break;
  }
```

However, when the code actually runs, the path is always printing as so(which returns an error, because the zeros in front of the month in the date are removed):

```
/v2/reports/time/team?from=2021701&to=2021731
```

Should be this instead:

```
/v2/reports/time/team?from=20210701&to=20210731
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/3855179

Comment: First suggestion - check how the [`switch` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is supposed to work. Yours is wrong. It's better to just use an `if`, since you only ever have two branches anyway. Might be even easier to [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3605214) instead of `switch`ing.

Comment: I will suggest you to check the length of month... if its `1` then add `0`

Comment: Where `month < 10` you're actually adding two leading zeros, the first here: `month = \`0${month}\`` and again in `path = \`...?from=${year}0${month}01&...\`` so the server is seeing say '202100831' and likely parsing it as '2021-00-83' or worse.

Comment: @RobG if the month is less than 10, then the condition will never trigger because for `7` for example `7 === true` is `false`.

Comment: @VALZ—always with the details, it's the *vibe* that matters. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch implementation is not correct, so only default is execute, I will suggest you first explore the switch in JavaScript, this will help you in future as well,

however I have modified the code, please have a look below

```
const date = new Date();
const year = date.getFullYear();
let month = date.getMonth();
let path = ``;
switch (true) {
  case month < 10:
    path = `/v2/reports/time/team?from=${year}0${month}01&to=${year}0${month}31`;
    break;
  default:
    path = `/v2/reports/time/team?from=${year}${month}01&to=${year}${month}31`;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't add zero directly into variable like that?

```js
const date = new Date();
const year = date.getFullYear();
let month = (date.getMonth() < 10) ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth();
let path = `/v2/reports/time/team?from=${year}${month}01&to=${year}${month}31`;

console.log(path);
```