# Always display 2 digits for date/time with `getDate`

Tags: javascript, getdate, gettime

I'm using javascript to display the current (live) date/time on a website. I want all the numbers (date, hour, minute, second) to always display with 2 digits. So if a number is (0-9) it is prefixed with a '0'

I've managed to do this for the time counter. But I can't seem to work the same code into `getDate` without breaking the script.

If someone could help with that it'd be greatly appreciated and also confirm if my approach isn't massively overcomplicated!

```js
function showDateTime() {
  var currentDate = document.getElementById("date");
  var currentTime = document.getElementById("time");

  var date = new Date();
  var dayList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var monthNames = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];
  var dayName = dayList[date.getDay()];
  var monthName = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
  var today = `${dayName} ${date.getDate()} ${monthName}`;

  var hour = ('0'+date.getHours()).substr(-2);
  var min = ('0'+date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
  var sec = ('0'+date.getSeconds()).substr(-2);

  var time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  currentDate.innerText = `${today}`;
  currentTime.innerText = `${time}`;
}
setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: check out this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date

Answer (score 0):

```
const date = new Date();
const now = date.toLocaleTimeString(); // "11:33:01"
```

You could also use const instead of var because the value will never change.

```
    function showDateTime() {
  const currentDate = document.getElementById("date");
  const currentTime = document.getElementById("time");

  const date = new Date();
  const dayList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  const monthNames = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];

  const dayName = dayList[date.getDay()];
  const monthName = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
  const today = `${dayName} ${date.getDate()} ${monthName}`;

  const time = date.toLocaleTimeString(); 

  currentDate.innerText = `${today}`;
  currentTime.innerText = `${time}`;
}
setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: Would that replace the `var today` bit in my code?