# Date format change

Tags: javascript, date, format

I would like to change the date format in my code like that - > 19.7.2016

Could anyone help me, please?

```
function calcWorkingDays(fromDate, days) {
    var count = 0;
    var m = new Date();
    while (count < days) {
        fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (fromDate.getDay() != 0 && fromDate.getDay() != 6) // Skip weekends
            count++;
    }
    return fromDate;
}
alert(calcWorkingDays(new Date(), 4));
```

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: I removed `java` from the title, since this is not a Java question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the `dateobject` to your likeness:

Extract the Day, Month and Year from your DateObject:

```
var month = fromDate.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
//January=0, February=1, etc

var day = fromDate.getUTCDate();
var year = fromDate.getUTCFullYear();

newdate = day + "." + month + "." + year;
```

Complete Example:

```
function calcWorkingDays(fromDate, days) {
    var count = 0;
    var m = new Date();
    while (count < days) {
        fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (fromDate.getDay() != 0 && fromDate.getDay() != 6) // Skip weekends
            count++;
    }

    var month = fromDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var day = fromDate.getUTCDate();
    var year = fromDate.getUTCFullYear();

    newdate = day + "." + month + "." + year;

    return newdate;
}
alert(calcWorkingDays(new Date(), 4));
```

Other possible examples are:

```
new Date().toISOString()
"2016-02-18T23:59:48.039Z"
new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
"2016-02-18"
new Date().toISOString().replace('-', '/').split('T')[0].replace('-', '/');
"2016/02/18"

new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0]
"2/18/2016"
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494888/4985572)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert date to string:

```
function calcWorkingDays(fromDate, days) {
    var count = 0;
    var m = new Date();
    while (count < days) {
        fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (fromDate.getDay() != 0 && fromDate.getDay() != 6) // Skip weekends
        count++;
}
     return fromDate.getDate()  + "." + (fromDate.getMonth()+1) + "." + fromDate.getFullYear();
```

}

alert(calcWorkingDays(new Date(), 4));