# How to convert date into this 'yyyy-MM-dd' format in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to convert current date into `'yyyy-MM-dd'` format in `.ts` file. In template it can easily be done by using date pipe. How to do that in typescript?

**In template:**

```
{{date  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

**How to convert in this format `'yyyy-MM-dd'` in typescript?**

I am just getting current date by using this.

```
this.date =  new Date();
```

but I need to convert it into the given format.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-use-pipes-in-services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date as dd/MM/yyyy in Angular 2 using pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/how-to-format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-in-angular-2-using-pipes)

Comment: i tried both but not working it might be due to some changes in Angular 2 final. because mentioned duplicates are from beta

Comment: This question is answered in the question linked by @Shil, read the second answer which utilizes constructor injection.

The one thing not present in that answer is the datepipe needs to be listed in the providers of the component or service if using DI.

Comment: What is your version of angular? I tested in [rc.2 version](http://plnkr.co/edit/vMSP5cT1XTAWi7oYBYmm?p=preview) that I [quote in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37931071/2290538) and [angular current version 2.1.1](http://plnkr.co/edit/f7Wih8ceKHQUDHKmYCpQ?p=preview), and its format standard works properly. This has been resolved in version rc.2 [as I quote here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37931071/2290538). If your angular is after rc.2 this should work if lower you should consider an alternative [as is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37859544/2290538) or to upgrade version of angular.

Comment: My  version is angular 2.0.0 final.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The date can be converted in typescript to this format `'yyyy-MM-dd'` by using Datepipe

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
...
constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe){}
...
myFunction(){
 this.date=new Date();
 let latest_date =this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

and just add Datepipe in 'providers' array of app.module.ts. Like this:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
...
providers: [DatePipe]
```

Comment: From a back-end perspective this is a good answer especially if one is consuming an API and the call returns an ill-formatted date.

Comment: you missed where to import this from: import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

Comment: now there's a built in `formatDate()` function, just import from `@angular/common` https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Answer (score 27):

The same problem I faced in my project. Thanks to @Umar Rashed, but I am going to explain it in detail.

First, Provide *Date Pipe* from app.module:

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

Import to your component and app.module:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Second, declare it under the constructor:

```
constructor(
    public datepipe: DatePipe
  ) {
```

Dates come **from the server** and parsed to console like this:

```
2000-09-19T00:00:00
```

I convert the date to how I need with this code;
**in TypeScript:**

```
this.datepipe.transform(this.birthDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Show from **HTML template:**

```
{{ user.birthDate }}
```

and **it is seen like this:**

```
19/09/2000
```

also seen on the web site like this:
[dates shown as it is filtered (click to see the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogySw.jpg)

Comment: Briliant , This is what developer need, not to append single day, month or year to create own format. cheers! mate... Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use formatDate

```
let formattedDt = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZZZZ', 'en_US')
```

Comment: works well in the static method. thanks.

Answer (score 15):

A simple solution would be to just write

```
this.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

date `.toLocaleDateString()`
time `.toLocaleTimeString()`
both `.toLocaleString()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Friend I can get data perfect ex: 30/08/2018 (date from Brazil), but if I want get only day or month or only years , how to do this ?

Comment: what you're looking for has been answered in the following
[**SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013255/how-to-get-year-month-day-from-a-date-object)

Answer (score 9):

**You can also try this.**

consider today's date **'28 Dec 2018'**(for example)

```
 this.date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

> new Date() we get as: Fri Dec 28 2018 11:44:33 GMT+0530 (India
>   Standard Time)
>
> toISOString will convert to : 2018-12-28T06:15:27.479Z
>
> slice(0,10) we get only first 10 characters as date which contains
>   yyyy-mm-dd : 2018-12-28.

Comment: Note that the ISO string will be in the GMT timezone, so your day might be off-by-one either way, depending on your timezone.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You completely missed the timezone. Have you tried the `2018-12-31T23:55:00.000Z`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const formatDate=(dateObj)=>{
const days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
const months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

const dateOrdinal=(dom)=> {
    if (dom == 31 || dom == 21 || dom == 1) return dom + "st";
    else if (dom == 22 || dom == 2) return dom + "nd";
    else if (dom == 23 || dom == 3) return dom + "rd";
    else return dom + "th";
};
return dateOrdinal(dateObj.getDate())+', '+days[dateObj.getDay()]+' '+ months[dateObj.getMonth()]+', '+dateObj.getFullYear();
}
const ddate = new Date();
const result=formatDate(ddate)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Example:20th, Wednesday September, 2020 <h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) if you have trouble with Angular. At least it is a quick workaround without spending too much time.

Comment: i am getting this error when using moment cannot call a namespace('moment')

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
today:string = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'/');
```