# ionic Display current time in format like MM , DD , YYYY

Tags: html, typescript, ionic3

I want to display my current date format like this
[Format I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlgCa.png)

Currently I'm using like this, this is the code in my home.ts

```
myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
```

I display the date in `home.html` like this

```
Date : {{myDate}}
```

and it show like this [Format I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh2z5.png)

How can I display it like the first image ?

I've done a lot of research and none of it meet my requirement.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40460346/2884011

Comment: You can also use it like this: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting ur date using `yourDate.toDateString()`
Generat2s somethibg like "Thu October 26 2015". If you dont want the day of the weak you can manipulate the string. If you really want it the way you stated you can use `string.split( )` and rearrange the resulting entries in the array