# 'null' result return after convert date into this 'yyyy-MM-dd' format

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

am follow the guide from [How to convert date into this 'yyyy-MM-dd' format in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377103/how-to-convert-date-into-this-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-angular-2/68513033#68513033)  and my return result = 'null' . can pls advise where is my mistake?

```
mydate: string ;
date: Date;

postObj={
    unitno:'',
    trackno:'',
    date: new Date(); 
};

addparcel() {
  
   this.mydate = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    
    console.log(this.postObj.unitno)
    console.log(this.postObj.trackno)
    console.log(this.mydate); 
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: add the complete code, not just a part of it

Comment: From your snippet, `this.date` is null. You only declare its type as `Date`, but you never assign a value to it.

Comment: tq for correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking out the angular documentation for datepipe here:

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

TL;DR

```
this.mydate = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

is wrong, it should be something like :

```
this.mydate = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'medium');
```

Now in your case I assume you want to convert it to Mysql timestamp, to do that I did this:

```
 this.dte = new Date();
  let aux = this.dte.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (this.dte.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + this.dte.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + this.dte.getHours() + ":" + this.dte.getMinutes() + ":" + this.dte.getSeconds();
```

I know it looks long, but it works 100%