# How to format java.sql.date to JavaScript Date received in JSON?

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring

I have this simple entity managed by spring.
I would like to work with the `endDate` and `startDate` fields that I receive them in JSON format in JavaScript

received JSON-

```
{
    "id": 151,
    "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "companyName5"
    },
    "category": "Automotive",
    "title": "Automotive",
    "description": "Automotive",
    "startDate": "2021-06-30",
    "endDate": "2022-09-30",
    "amount": 50,
    "price": 50,
    "image": "imgPath"
}
```

Java entity -

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Table(name = "coupon")
public class Coupon {

    // FIELDS
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;  

    @ManyToOne()
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"email","password","coupons"})
    private Company company; 

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category; 

    private String title;
    private String description; 
    private Date startDate; 
    private Date endDate; 
    private int amount; 
    private double price; 
    private String image; 
}
```

Coupon Model in JavaScript (TypeScript)

```
class Coupon {
    public id: number = 0; 
    public comapnyId:number = 0;
    public category:string = "";
    public title:string = "";
    public description: string = "";
    public startDate: string;
    public endDate: string;
    public amount:number = 0;
    public price:number = 0;
    public image:string = "";
}
```

Comment: What, in particular, is not working about the code you've posted?

Comment: When I receive in the client the date from the Json, when i try to work with it or format it, it is `Undefined`

Comment: Hi Daniel, you can accept my answer by ticking the green Done icon if it solved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
const startDate="2021-06-30";
const jsObjStartDate = new Date(startDate);
console.log(jsObjStartDate);
console.log(jsObjStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)) // YYYY-MM-DD
console.log(jsObjStartDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US')) // M/D/YYYY
console.log(jsObjStartDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE')) // D.M.YYYY
console.log(jsObjStartDate.toLocaleDateString('pt-PT')) // DD/MM/YYYY
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60609524/7344164)

Answer (score 1):

```
    // parse JSON to JS object, get startDate and endDate fields via object destructuring   
    const {startDate, endDATE} = JSON.parse(`{
        "id": 151,
        "company": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "companyName5"
        },
        "category": "Automotive",
        "title": "Automotive",
        "description": "Automotive",
        "startDate": "2021-06-30",
        "endDate": "2022-09-30",
        "amount": 50,
        "price": 50,
        "image": "imgPath"
    }`);
    
    // instantiate Date js objects with startDate and endDate provided to Date constructor
    const jsObjStartDate = new Date(startDate);
    const jsObjEndDate = new Date(endDate);
```