# how do I get only the day displayed?

Tags: javascript, date, format

I am absolutely new and have not found a suitable answer yet (or was too blind to see it). I would like the date to be displayed to me in dd/mm/yyyy format. Currently it shows me the day in milliseconds though? Can someone help me?

```js
var oneweekago = new Date();
var month = oneweekago.getMonth() +1
var day = oneweekago.setDate(oneweekago.getDate() - 7)
var year = oneweekago.getFullYear()
document.write(day + "/" + month + "/" + year)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get year/month/day from a date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013255/how-to-get-year-month-day-from-a-date-object)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code displays last's week date

```
<script>
const today = new Date()
const yesterday = new Date(today)

yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 7)

today.toDateString()
yesterday.toDateString()
console.log(yesterday)
</script>
```

Comment: yes it does. but i need the date  for 7 days ago

Comment: @HappyGilmore updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for `oneWeekAgo.toLocaleDateString()`

```
var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7)
document.write(oneWeekAgo.toLocaleDateString())
```

Comment: This helps! But its the format: "mm/dd/yyyy" and i need "dd/mm/yyyy". Thank you!